# Extract features from Colour-only images

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision, feature-extraction

I want to extract features for A.I. based colour classification. I'm aware of using histogram of colour spaces as vector of features, however using multiple colour space histograms will make my neural network inputs way too large. A single RGB colour space will give me (3x256 = 768 features). Using more than one colour space for different variations of the same image is just too many features. I'm avoiding using the average of the histograms because I would like to know the colour distribution of the image. The images just consist of colour, no edges or objects present. Any suggestions for what algorithms to use is welcomed.

These are examples of the colour images that I want to work with
[image: Colour image]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to look into a classification solely based on color, color histograms are definitely the right choice. You do not want to use the whole RGB color space as this will produce a huge feature space as you have already noticed.

Instead, you should first look into **binning** your histogram (like explained [here](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/understanding-histograms.php)). This will already reduce your feature space by a factor of your choice.

You could further improve your results and reduce the number of features by excluding color ranges that you are simply not interested in (in your case probably blue~red). You could also find correct centers for your bins, depending on the most frequently occurring color centers, e.g by doing *k-means* in color-space.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see your problem is that you want to characterize your image by the dominant color, a simple classification scheme without using any neural network can be to find the dominant color in your picture. Below is a MATLAB snippet of how to do it.

```
image = imread('image.png');
imshow(image);
histR = imhist(image(:,:,1));
histG = imhist(image(:,:,2));
histB = imhist(image(:,:,3));
[~, idxR] = max(histR);
[~, idxG] = max(histG);
[~, idxB] = max(histB);
dominant_colour_feature = [idxR, idxG, idxB] - 1; % 1 is subtracted because of MATLAB indexing scheme
```

I am not sure, what kind of color classification you are looking for. The kind of images you happen to work with can be simply classified using this approach. Depending upon your requirements, we can further modify the scheme.

I tried this on one of your image:
[image: Sample Image]
and the output was (254,228,0) which pretty much looks like [this](https://convertingcolors.com/rgb-color-255_248_0.html).
May be you are looking for something else.